# F#: How to write the classic swap function?

Tags: f#, pass-by-reference

In C# the classic swap function is:

```
void swap (ref int a, ref int b){
     int temp = a;
     a = b;
     b = temp;
}

int a = 5;
int b = 10;
swap( ref a, ref b);
```

How would I write that with F#?

(Note, I do not want the functional equivalent. I actually need pass by reference semantics.)

Comment: If you don't want the function version, then why use F#?

Comment: Does it really matter why? Question is a question...still deserves an answer.

Comment: F# isn't an island. In this case I'm working on wrappers for SQL stored procedures which rely heavily on output parameters. I need this to sit between the function-style API and the sql-style API.

Comment: I think it does. You can offer better advice if you know what the person is trying to do.

Comment: @jrista true, but sometimes context and motivation makes a difference in the answer. In this case I was just curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following

```
let swap (left : 'a byref) (right : 'a byref) =
  let temp = left
  left <- right
  right <- temp
```

Answer (score 10):

Example to Jared's code:

```
let mutable (a, b) = (1, 2)

let swap (left : 'a byref) (right : 'a byref) =
  let temp = left
  left <- right
  right <- temp

printfn "a: %i - b: %i" a b
swap (&a) (&b)
printfn "a: %i - b: %i" a b
```

Normally, you would use `ref-cells` instead of mutable let's.

Comment: Are you sure about that. I thought I read that one should prefer mutables when possible.

Answer (score 2):

/// A function that swaps the order of two values in a tuple

```
let Swap (a, b) = (b, a)
```

Comment: This question is not about swapping in tuples, but about something like `let temp = a;a<-b;b<-temp`